# How to add and retrieve custom meta data to a video file in iOS programming?

Tags: ios, video, metadata

I am trying to save video with custom metadata relevant for my app and trying to retrieve it when the user selects that video from the library. I am not sure if I am saving the meta data right as I am not able to see anything when I try to retrieve the metadata. I am also not sure if I am retrieving the meta data correctly. I am new to iOS, any help is appreciated. I have searched many threads and developer library but could not get this to work.

I am trying to save metadata in the recordingDidFinishToOutputFileURL delegate function. Video is getting saved in the library.

```
NSMutableArray *metadata = [NSMutableArray array];
    AVMutableMetadataItem *mi = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];
    mi.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle;
    mi.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;
    mi.value = @"title";
    [metadata addObject:mi];

    NSLog(@"Output saving:%@",outputFileURL);
    AVAsset *video = [AVAsset assetWithURL:outputFileURL];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession      exportSessionWithAsset:video presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    exportSession.metadata = metadata;
    exportSession.outputURL = outputFileURL;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"done processing video!");
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil); 
    }];
```

I am trying to retrieve the video in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate function to check the metadata but not able to see anything in the completionhandler function

```
        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        video_selected = TRUE;
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        NSLog(@"video has %@", videoURL.path);
        AVAsset *videoAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
        NSLog(@"Loading metadata...");
        NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"commonMetadata", nil];
        NSMutableArray *metadata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [videoAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^{

            [metadata removeAllObjects];
            for (NSString *format in [videoAsset availableMetadataFormats])
            {
                [metadata addObjectsFromArray:[videoAsset metadataForFormat:format]];
                NSLog(@"Printing metadata-%@",metadata);
            }


        }];
```

Comment: Are you able to save the file to a regular computer to look at the metadata there?

Comment: why are you trying to add a metadata instead of creating a new folder in your photos library? so you can save and retrieve the videos/photos that are relevant to your app?

Comment: Only support mov file type? not mp4

Answer (score 0):

check your errors. You're exporting to where the file already exists so it's exporting into itself which won't work. Just export to a different location

Answer (score 0):

These keys work fine:

- AVMetadataCommonKeyAuthor
- AVMetadataCommonKeyDescription
- AVMetadataCommonKeyCopyrights

MP4 files support the ISO userdata keyspace and the iTunes metadata keyspace. The above keys don't have an ISO userdata mapping, so that's why they're not working. Likewise, you can't put AVMetadataQuickTimeMetadataKey* in an MP4 file because it doesn't support that keyspace.

```
var metadata: [AVMetadataItem] = []
let mi = AVMutableMetadataItem()
mi.identifier = AVMetadataIdentifier.commonIdentifierDescription
mi.keySpace = .common
mi.value = "Milan Description" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
metadata.append(mi)

let mi1 = AVMutableMetadataItem()
mi1.identifier = AVMetadataIdentifier.commonIdentifierCopyrights
mi1.keySpace = .common
mi1.value = "Milan copy" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
metadata.append(mi1)

print("Output saving:\(trackObj.getTrackUrl())")
let video = AVAsset(url: trackObj.getTrackUrl())
let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: video, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
exportSession?.metadata = metadata

exportSession?.outputURL = volumeBoosterViewModel.audioResultRootFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(trackObj.filePathName)
exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp3

exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {[weak self]
    () -> Void in
    if exportSession!.status == AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed  {
        // All is working fine!!
        print("success")
        //get metadata
        let asset = AVAsset(url: Your url)
        if asset.commonMetadata.count > 0 {
            for item in asset.metadata {
                //get metadata
                print(item.value)
            }
        }
    }
})
```